# Insert a blank line before a particular line in multiple files

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to insert a blank line before particular line in multiple files using cmd.

Consider the below file which has:

```
Apple
Orange 
Tree
[One]
Black
```

Expected Output :

```
Apple
Orange 
Tree

[One]
Black
```

Before the line `[One]` a blank line needs to be inserted.

Can someone help in commands using cmd?

Comment: Please review [Ask] and [MCVE].  Are you sure you want to abandon your Powershell effort for a cmd script?  Powershell would be a much better scripting language for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with [replacer.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/replacer.bat):

```
call replacer.bat "e?C:\content.txt" "[One]" "\u000d\u000A[One] Black"
```

the `e?` before the file name is for evaluation of unicode symbols.

Comment: @user245596 - you've changed the content of your question. Can you try my edited code?